# How to include Microsoft graph in scopes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, swagger-ui

I am working on Azure AD and .net core application. I have a swagger application which will do authentication and authorization. Below is my swagger config.

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });

    c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
    {
        Type = "oauth2",
        Flow = "implicit",
        AuthorizationUrl = swaggerUIOptions.AuthorizationUrl,
        TokenUrl = swaggerUIOptions.TokenUrl,
        Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
        { 
            { "Read", "https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read" }
        }
    });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
    { 
        { "oauth2", new [] { "readAccess", "writeAccess" } }
    });
});
```

Below is my config in Configure.

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
    c.OAuthClientId(swaggerUIOptions.ClientId);
    c.OAuthClientSecret(swaggerUIOptions.ClientSecret);
    c.OAuthRealm(azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId);
    c.OAuthAppName("Swagger");
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
});
```

Below are my `AuthorizationUrl` and `TokenUrl`

```
"AuthorizationUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
"TokenUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token"
```

Below is API permission set in azure ad.
[image]

When I try to get token(I selected scope checkmark) in swagger I get below error.

> The application swagger asked for Read that doesn't exist on the resource

Also, I have one more app for back end APIs.  When we try to get access token, can we the same token to call Graph APIs and backend APIs?

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of using Swagger here? Typically Swagger is used for documenting _your_ APIs, not to connect to external APIs. Graph doesn't publish a Swagger file so I'm not sure what your expectations are.

Comment: `{ "Read", "https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read" }` the first `"Read"` is probably the cause of your error and can be removed - even though I'm also unsure what you mean to accomplish with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The application swagger asked for Read that doesn't exist on the
>   resource.

There is no `Read` permission under Microsoft Graph api. You can use `User.Read` or `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read`

> Also, I have one more app for back end APIs. When we try to get access
>   token, can we the same token to call Graph APIs and backend APIs?

You can use this token to call Graph APIs, but need to add the permissions for the api. You can not use the same token to call different apis under different resources.